# add 2 more attribute values to the magento order view page section

Tags: attributes, orders, admin-panel

[image]in the magento admin panel, if we go for Orders section

and if we click on one order, we can see the Product name and sku at the bottom.

i want to add 2 more attributes to the order section.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify the Magento version but here is the solution for CE 1.8.1.0 (might also work for others):

The product name and SKU are output in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml`. You will find a variable `$_item` which is an object of the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`.

If you want to output data which is saved in the order item, you can directly use the order item:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getSomeValue()) ?>
```

If you need data which is only saved in the product itself, you can get the product and echo its value:

```
<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
```

Be aware that the same template is used for other pages like the invoice, shipment page and so on and there may be different templates for other product types.

Comment: thanks a lot, i only posted question.... i got the solution.... you are a life saver....

Comment: I follwed your solution, it's worked in one site, when i tried same solution in another site, it's

strange that it's not working in another site. both site are 1.9 version....

any idea why it's not working in another site?

Comment: If it's working on one site and not on the other my first suspicion would be that some site-specific extension / adjustment either changes the behaviour or the template of this grid. You could check if your template file is really used at this position and which data the order item / product contains. You can also check if you find out more by [debugging the store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429). If you don't find the reason you could post that as a new question given you have some information to work with for the users here.

Comment: hi,

it's really strange,

but i edited here too : app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml file.

than i got result.... thanks a lot again....

Comment: please help me to display on invoice page....

Answer (score 1):

you need to adjust 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
This is the table you are looking for. Add what ever you want to add here :)

Comment: hi, you are right.... i did it....

Comment: please help me to display on invoice page....

Answer (score -1):

This works great. However if the product is variable it will not work. 
I Need a barcode "EAN" to be displayed as attribute. It works as single products but show empty as variable.

```
<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getEan(); ?>
```

How to solve that?

Comment: if you post new question with these details, you may get solution soon.....